# Entering simple and grouped products

Tags: magento2, grouped-products

Will the layout be the same for each product being entered, if it's just simple only or if I add grouped as well. I may down the road have more so would it be better to always do grouped too and simple for each one that I enter? Also is it better to add simple first then go back to grouped after you have completed the simple products?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add first simple products and then select all them in a grouped products. But yes you can add more products in group product according to your need.